# ¿desactivar cin despues de 5 segundos cuando no se escriba nada?

Tags: c++

buenas tardes tengo un proyecto sencillo de suma para pequeños no puedo implementar que cuando aparesca la suma en pantalla el usuario tenga solo 5 segundos para responder si no responde pasa a la siguiente suma pero se registraria como resultado fallido no puedo hacer que el ingreso de datos solo este activo 5 segundos y luego continue con la siguiente linea de codigo.
Aagradeceria una guia de donde tengo que empezar a leer porque no creo que sea con cin

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

En C++ estandar no se puede lograr lo que querés.

No obstante, podrías investigar la librería ncurses, si es que te encontrás sobre Linux, que te permite lanzar la función `timeout` para luego utilizar `getstr()` o `scanw()`.

Desconozco como trabaja PDCurses, que es una alternativa de ncurses para Windows, pero podés investigar en [PDCurses](https://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm).

Depende mucho la implementación requerida, pero lo que podrías hacer con C++ estandar y de manera sencilla es controlar el tiempo previo al cin contra el tiempo posterior a que el usuario ingresa un valor, y en caso de que supere una cantidad de tiempo establecida actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: Idealmente evitemos responder a preguntas mal planteadas pues terminan cerradas, de hecho lleva dos de cinco votos para ello

Comment: @BetaM idealmente se debería comentar porqué está mal formulada para votar el cierre de la misma para que el autor la pueda corregir. Al ser un usuario nuevo me pareció bueno darle una chance de que obtenga un respuesta, y si bien la pregunta no está bien formulada, se entiende donde apunta.